# Efficient php code to insert array data into mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

So I have a flatfile db in the format of 
    username:$SHA$1010101010101010$010110010101010010101010100101010101001010:255.255.255.255:1342078265214

Each record on a new line... about 5000+ lines.. I want to import it into a mysql table. Normally I'd do this using phpmyadmin and "file import", but now I want to automate this process by using php to download the db via ftp and then clean up the existing table data and upload the updated db.

```
id(AUTH INCREMENT) | username | password | ip | lastlogin
```

The script I've got below for the most part works.. although php will generate an error: 
"PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" I believe I could just increase this time, but on remote server I doubt I'll be allowed, so I need to find better way of doing this.

Only about 1000 records will get inserted into the database before that timeout...

The code I'm using is below.. I will say right now I'm not a pro in php and this was mainly gathered up and cobbled together. I'm looking for some help to make this more efficient as I've heard that doing an insert like this is just bad.  And it really sounds bad aswel, as a lot of disk scratching when I run this script on local pc.. I mean why does it want to kill the hdd for doing such a seemingly simple task.

```
<?php
require ('Connections/local.php');

$wx = array_map('trim',file("auths.db"));
$username = array();
$password = array();
$ip = array();
$lastlogin = array();
foreach($wx as $i => $line) {

        $tmp = array_filter(explode(':',$line));
        $username[$i] = $tmp[0];
        $password[$i] = $tmp[1];
        $ip[$i] = $tmp[2];
        $lastlogin[$i] = $tmp[3];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO authdb (username,password,ip,lastlogin) VALUES('$username[$i]', '$password[$i]', '$ip[$i]', '$lastlogin[$i]') ") or die(mysql_error()); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Inserting multiple rows in one query should significantly improve performance.

Comment: Since you're using `mysql_query` without [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) you should probably be using `mysqli` or PDO for your own safety.

Comment: I'd recommend switching to using [fgets](http://uk.php.net/fgets), rather than splitting the whole file into an array, that would be a speed increase also.

Comment: I'll look into using fgets, though I think my current problem I'm really having here is getting this into mysql db in such a way that php doesn't timeout beforehand.

Comment: @alfasin - I'll assume your native language isn't english. aswel --> as well, (or 'also', or 'additionally') - it's a spelling mistake. :)

Comment: @enhzflep is this something you'd expect any native English speaker to know ? :) Thanks for the translation!

Comment: You're welcome alfasin. I think many (most?) native speakers would pick that mistake up. Heck, with txt-speak these days, 1/2 the kids probably think it's perfectly formed English. :laugh:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, with bound parameters and PDO.

```
<?php
require ('Connections/local.php');

$wx = array_map('trim',file("auths.db"));
$username = array();
$password = array();
$ip = array();
$lastlogin = array();

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$ip;dbname=$database", $dbUsername, $dbPassword);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$mysql_query = "INSERT INTO authdb (username,password,ip,lastlogin) VALUES(:username, :password, :ip, :lastlogin)";
$statement = $dbh->prepare($mysql_query);

foreach($wx as $i => $line) {
        set_time_limit(0);

        $tmp = array_filter(explode(':',$line));
        $username[$i] = $tmp[0];
        $password[$i] = $tmp[1];
        $ip[$i] = $tmp[2];
        $lastlogin[$i] = $tmp[3];

        $params = array(":username"  => $username[$i],
                        ":password"  => $password[$i],
                        ":ip"        => $ip[$i],
                        ":lastlogin" => $lastlogin[$i]);
        $statement->execute($params);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing that..  I tested it out straight away, though I got some bad news. Php still timed out at 30seconds. //1,188 records got inserted  ... I tested the original script I had and managed //1,085 inserted records. Is there anyway to get around this php limit? other than increasing the limit?

Comment: What is the value for `max_execution_time` in your php.ini ? Are you running this from the command line?

Comment: I'm just running the php script from  h**p://localhost  ... Also php.ini is max_execution_time = 30    .Which is about right for the "PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" errors I get. Like I said I could change that here, but I don't think I would be allowed to on the remote server, where I'm ideally wanting to have this script so its quicker to get the db updated.

Comment: Try adding `set_time_limit(0)` inside your foreach loop.

Comment: I'm glad. This _should_ work on the remote server, unless PHP is running in safe mode on it. Feel free to accept the answer I provided if it helped with your mysql. This bound parameter style is not only efficient, it's quite safe.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `set_time_limit` within the foreach... that's just crazy talk ;) `set_time_limit` would be fine at the top of the script... otherwise you'll be constantly requesting the same 'Limit of maximum execution time' again and again.

Comment: Oh it works brilliantly on the remote server... lol it took 160seconds to donwload the file via ftp using php and then do this script storing everything into my local mysql.  On the remote server the same thing 1.8seconds  lol  ...I almost thought it something had gone wrong, nope all 5000+ records inserted. Thanks   ...Would that set_time_limit have been fine on my own script version??

Comment: "You shouldn't need the set_time_limit within the foreach... that's just crazy talk ;) "  Yeh I did do that, shaved off like .2 second on the remote server time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending queries to server one by one in the form

```
insert into table (x,y,z) values (1,2,3)
```

You should use extended insert syntax, as in:

```
insert into table (x,y,z) values (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9),...
```

This will increase insert performance by miles. However you need to be careful about how many rows you insert in one statement, since there is a limit to the size of a single SQL can be. So, I'd say start with 100 row packs and see how it goes, then adjust pack size accordingly. Chances are your insert time will go down to like 5 seconds, putting it way under max_execution_time limit.